# Link 2 MySQL tables and display data but sort by ID

Tags: mysql

I have two tables within the same database, one for file info (for files that have been uploaded to the server) and the other is for notes (notes that have been pinned to an event).

When the user opens a specific event it searches each table (File and Notes) to see if there has been any Files or Notes uploaded that are pinned to that event and it does this by searching for EventId in both tables.

I was to display the results in one list so I basically want the results to merge into one and I want to be able to loop through it and if ID 1 is from File then it will display something from File and if ID 2 is from Notes then it will display a note.

**File Table Structure**
FileID | EventId | FileName | FilePath | FileTimestamp

**Notes Table Structure**
NoteId | EventId | noteContents | noteTimestamp

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `UNION` would do

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        1 as isFile,
        f.FileID as id,
        CONCAT(f.FilePath, f.FileName) as content,
        f.FileTimestamp as eventTimestamp
    FROM File f WHERE f.EventId = @id
    UNION
    SELECT
        0 as isFile,
        n.NoteId as id,
        n.noteContents as content,
        n.noteTimestamp as eventTimestamp
    FROM Notes n WHERE n.EventId = @id
) as x
```

Just replace `@id` with your own variable / parameter / value

You can add an `order by id` after all that but I don't think both tables are using the same sequence to generate their IDs

Comment: he wont be able to do a lookup on eventId in his loop this way. but it could work depending what he wants

Comment: The OP states he already knows the EventID, he only needs the attachments which can be either notes or files

Comment: yeah not 100% on what op means by list. list for 1 event. or list of events with notes and files attached

Comment: "When the user opens a specific event" - OP

Comment: you could add a Type column of 'note' or 'file' and then sort by it first and then id to get the order right

Comment: I've added a boolean `isFile` already